# Complexity of coin algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o, complexity-theory

Can anyone tell me the complexity (Big O notation preferred) of this code? It finds the least number of "coins" needed to make a target sum. 
To do this it calculates the least number of coins for each number up to the target starting from 1. Each number is worked out based on the possible pairs of numbers that could sum to it, and the pair with the smallest cost is used. An example hopefully makes this clearer

If the "coins" are {1, 3, 4} and the target is 13 then it iterates from 1 to 13, where the cost of 2 the minimum from (0+2, 1+1), the c(5) is the smallest cost of (c(0)+c(5), c(1)+c(4), c(2)+c(3)), etc up to c(13)

This is a version of the knapsack problem and I'm wondering how to define its complexity?

Code:

```
import java.util.*;

public class coinSumMinimalistic {
    public static final int TARGET = 12003;
    public static int[] validCoins = {1, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10, 12};

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arrays.sort(validCoins);

        sack();
    }

    public static void sack() {
        Map<Integer, Integer> coins = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>();
        coins.put(0, 0);
        int a = 0;
        for(int i = 1; i <= TARGET; i++) {
            if(a < validCoins.length && i == validCoins[a]) {
                coins.put(i, 1);
                a++;
            } else coins.put(i, -1);
        }
        for(int x = 2; x <= TARGET; x++) {
            if(x % 5000 == 0) System.out.println("AT: " + x);
            ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            for(int i = 0; i <= x / 2; i++) {
                int j = x - i;
                list.add(i);
                list.add(j);
            }
            coins.put(x, min(list, coins));
        }
        System.out.println("It takes " + coins.get(TARGET) + " coins to reach the target of " + TARGET);
    }

    public static int min(ArrayList<Integer> combos, Map<Integer, Integer> coins) {
        int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < combos.size() - 1; i += 2) {
            int x = coins.get(combos.get(i));
            int y = coins.get(combos.get(i + 1));
            if(x < 0 || y < 0) continue;
            else {
                total = x + y;
                if(total > 0 && total < min) {
                    min = total;
                }
            }
        }
        int t = (min == Integer.MAX_VALUE || min < 0) ? -1:min;
        return t;
    }
}
```

EDIT: Upon research I think that the complexity is O(k*n^2) where n is the target, and k is the number of coins supplied, is this correct?

Comment: I've searched for similar problems but couldn't find anything with big O notation, and on the wiki page it simply says with dynamic programming it is psuedo-polynomial.
In addition, I know the problem depends on both the target and the coins, so it is more than just n

Comment: Well pseudo-polynomial is still NP-complete, thus exponential in the number of coins, but limited to a polynomial of the queried number to compose. But since numbers are usually represented as numbers with radix greater than or equal to two, it can scale exponential with the number of bits.

Comment: @CommuSoft I don't quite follow, say I have k coins with a sum m, the complexity is related to o(m^k)?

Comment: No, it is *O(m^l)* with *l* a parameter. But *m=O(r^k)* with *r* a parameter.

Comment: ok that makes more sense, and r is just another parameter?

Comment: euh yes, that was a typo. I'm currently writing a more extensive answer. Although I think your implementation is not completely optimal with better datastructures you can certainly do this.

Comment: Given that a) the target is huge compared to the largest coin, and b) you have a coin with value 1, you should probably be burning the candle from the other end.

Comment: @spyr03: see first version of the answer, I will try to expand it.

Comment: @user3386109 I'm not sure how to do that, do you mean in the min function start from the pairs that are almost equal and go out, or from target down to 2? If I start from target there is no guarantee that it will be optimal?

Comment: Any reason why not using a simpler DP approach, where instead of considering all pairs we consider on each step only k options? (i.e. V[i]=min[c:c1,...ck](V[i-c])+1. This would produce an O(k*n) algorithm.

Comment: @EyalSchneider I don't follow how this would work, can you give a really small example?

Comment: @spyr03: The idea is looping from 1 to n, and filling the array V. On each step i, to achieve V[i] you must consider all smaller values that can reach V[i] by the addition of a single coin from the set. For example, consider the coins {1,2,5}, and the step which calculates V[7]. At this point you already have V=[1,1,2,2,1,2]. Now, V[7] is the smallest among V[6]+1 , V[5]+1 , v[2]+1, which is 2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I thinky the code you provided is kind of chaotic. So this post is more about the conceptual algorithm instead of the real algorithm. This can differ a bit since for instance insertion in an `ArrayList<T>` is not *O(1)*, but I'm confident that you can use good datastructures (for instance `LinkedList<T>`s) for this  to let all operations run in constant time.

What your algorithm basically does is the following:

1. It starts with a map that maps all the given coins to one: it requires one coin to achieve the value on the coin.
2. For each iteration, it mixes all already achieved values with all already achieved values. The result is thus the sum of the coins and it takes at the sum of the *number* of coins unless it was already present in the collection.
3. This step you **forgot**: kick out values **strictly larger** than the requested value: since all coins are strictly positive, you will never be able to construct a value with such composition less than the requested value.
4. You keep doing this until you have *constructed* the requested coin value.
5. If at iteration *i* all **new** values added to the set are **strictly larger** than the requested value, you can stop: the requested value can't be constructed.

The parameters are:

- *n*: the number of coins.
- *r*: the requested value.

A first observation is that each step of (2.) requires *O(s^2)* time with *s* the number of elements in the set at the start of the iteration: this is because you match every value with every value.

A second observation is that you can never have more elements in the set than the requested value. This means that *s* is bounded by *O(r)* (we assume all coins are integers, thus the set can contain at most all integer values from 0 to *r-1*). Step (2.) has thus a maximum time complexity of O(r^2).

And furthermore the set evolves progressively: at each iteration, you will always construct a *new* value that is at least one larger than the maximum thus far. As a consequence, the algorithm will perform maximum *O(r)* iterations.

This implies that the algorithm has a time-complexity of *O(r^3)*: *r* times *O(r^2)*.

---

*Why is the behavior exponential and thus at least NP-hard?*

A first argument is that it comes down on how you represent **input**: in many cases, numbers are represented using a system with a *radix* greater than or equal to `2`. This means that with *k* characters, you can represent a value that scales with *O(g^k)* with *g* the radix. Thus exponential. In other words, if you use a `32`-bit number, worst case, *r=O(2^32)*. So if you take this as input, there is an exponential part. If you would encode the target using *unary* notation, the algorithm is in *P*. But of course that's a bit like the *padding-argument*: given you provide enough useless input data (exponential or even super-exponential), all algorithms are in *P*, but you don't buy much with this.

A second argument is that if you leave the the requested value out of the *input*, you can only state that you start with *n* coins. You know that the number of iterations is fixed: you see the target value as an unknown constant. Each iteration, the total number of values in the `Map<Integer,Integer>` potentially squares. This thus means that the computational effort is:

```
n+n^2+n^4+n^6+...n^(log r)
^  ^                    ^
|  \-- first iteration  \-- end of algorithm
\-- insertion
```

It is clear that this behavior is exponential in *n*.